# How to rewrite react class into hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please, could someone explain the process converting classes into hooks ? That could really help me to learn more about hooks?
I'm trying to rewrite Lightbox but got stuck.

[My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lightbox-zxuqg)

Comment: Have you read the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)? That should help you to get started.

Comment: You can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-elion-ow4mz?file=/src/LightBox.js) for reference. The difference between `setState` in class components and the function that sets state when using hooks, is that in the latter case you need to merge the state object yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const Lightbox = (props) => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState({
    currentIndex: 0,
    isOpen: false,
    images: [...props.images],
    left: "-100vw",
    transition: "1s ease",
    imageStack: [],
  });

  const openLightBox = (index) => {
    let images = myState.images;
    let stack = [images[index]];
    if (index - 1 < 0) {
      stack.unshift(images[images.length - 1]);
    } else {
      stack.unshift(images[index - 1]);
    }
    if (index + 1 === images.length) {
      stack.push(images[0]);
    } else {
      stack.push(images[index + 1]);
    }
    setMyState({
      currentIndex: index,
      isOpen: true,
      imageStack: stack,
    });
  };

  const closeLightBox = () => {
    console.log(mySate.isOpen);
    setMyState({
      isOpen: false,
      imageStack: [],
    });
  };
  const changeImage = (direction) => {
    const { images } = myState;
    if (direction === "previous") {
      setMyState({
        transition: "1s ease",
        left: `${parseInt(myState.left, 0) + 100}vw`,
      });
      let stack = myState.imageStack;
      let first = "";
      if (images.indexOf(stack[0]) === 0) {
        first = images[images.length - 1];
      } else {
        first = images[images.indexOf(stack[0]) - 1];
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        stack.unshift(first);
        stack.pop();
        setMyState({
          imageStack: stack,
          transition: "",
          left: `${parseInt(myState.left, 0) - 100}vw`,
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (direction === "next") {
      setMyState({
        transition: "1s ease",
        left: `${parseInt(myState.left, 0) - 100}vw`,
      });
      let stack = myState.imageStack;
      let last = "";
      if (images.indexOf(stack[stack.length - 1]) === images.length - 1) {
        last = images[0];
      } else {
        last = images[images.indexOf(stack[stack.length - 1]) + 1];
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        stack.push(last);
        stack.shift();
        setMyState({
          imageStack: stack,
          transition: "",
          left: `${parseInt(myState.left, 0) + 100}vw`,
        });
      }, 1000);
    }

    const { images, imageStack } = myState;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!images && <h1>No images passed</h1>}
        {images &&
          images.map((img) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={img}
                src={img}
                alt={img}
                style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
                onClick={() => openLightBox(images.indexOf(img))}
              />
            );
          })}
        {myState.isOpen && (
          <div style={styles.container}>
            <div style={styles.overlay} onClick={() => closeLightBox()} />
            <div
              onClick={() => closeLightBox()}
              style={{
                ...styles.lightbox,
                left: myState.left,
                transition: myState.transition,
              }}
            >
              <div style={styles.imageOuter}>
                <img
                  src={imageStack[0]}
                  alt={imageStack[0]}
                  style={styles.image}
                />
              </div>
              <div style={styles.imageOuter}>
                <img
                  src={imageStack[1]}
                  alt={imageStack[1]}
                  style={styles.image}
                />
              </div>
              <div style={styles.imageOuter}>
                <img
                  src={imageStack[2]}
                  alt={imageStack[2]}
                  style={styles.image}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <h1
              style={styles.buttonPrevious}
              onClick={() => changeImage("previous")}
            >
              previous
            </h1>
            <h1 style={styles.buttonNext} onClick={() => changeImage("next")}>
              next
            </h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const styles = {
    container: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
    overlay: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: "100vw",
      height: "100vh",
      background: "black",
    },
    buttonPrevious: {
      color: "black",
      position: "absolute",
      top: "50%",
      left: 0,
    },
    buttonNext: {
      color: "black",
      position: "absolute",
      top: "50%",
      right: 0,
    },
    lightbox: {
      height: "100vh",
      position: "absolute",
      transition: "ease 1s",
      display: "flex",
    },
    image: {
      maxWidth: "100vw",
      maxHeight: "100vh",
    },
    imageOuter: {
      position: "relative",
      width: "100vw",
      height: "100vh",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
  };

  const App = () => {
    const cats = [
      "//placekitten.com/1500/500",
      "//placekitten.com/4000/3000",
      "//placekitten.com/800/1200",
      "//placekitten.com/1500/1500",
    ];
    return <Lightbox images={cats} />;
  };
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Wow...thank you. God bless you.

Comment: My pleasure :) Please mark it as answer !

Comment: Thank you. Just found out how to mark too)) sorry for delay

Comment: One more question... should we use useEffect for this?              
  ```componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      images: this.props.images
    });
  }```

Comment: @Paula that's not necessary. You can pass it to the state directly, how it's done in the example

Comment: I see). Thank you so much... )))